# How do i update one Jquery Chosen Dropdown on another chosen dropdown Selection Change

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

My Scenario is this

I need to create an attendance list so I used two jQuery chosen boxes (multi-select dropdown) for this.

One for Attended people and another one for absent people. What I want is when I select a particular person form the attended People select box, they must not be available in the Absent people select box. Can some one please help me?

Here is my coding segment

```
<section>
<label for="text_field">Attended People</label>
                <div>
                    <select data-placeholder="Select Employees" class="chzn-select" id="employees" multiple="true" style="width:350px;" tabindex="4" name="employees[]">

                        <?php
                        $query2 = "SELECT * FROM `employee` WHERE `company_id`= $compnay_id";
                        $sql_result2 = mysql_query($query2);
                        while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result2)) {
                            ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $row2['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row2['name']; ?></option>
                        <?php } ?>

                    </select>

                </div>

            </section> 
            <section><label for="text_field">Absented People</label>
                <div>
                    <select data-placeholder="Select Employees" class="chzn-select" id="employees2" multiple="true" style="width:350px;" tabindex="4" name="employees2[]">

                        <?php
                        $query2 = "SELECT * FROM `employee` WHERE `company_id`= $compnay_id";
                        $sql_result2 = mysql_query($query2);
                        while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result2)) {
                            ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $row2['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row2['name']; ?></option>
                        <?php } ?>

                    </select>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        $(".chzn-select").chosen();
                        $(".chzn-select-deselect").chosen({allow_single_deselect: true});
                        $("")
                    </script>
                </div>

            </section>
```

Comment: please post your HTML, not the PHP

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar question going at the moment.  If I understand you correctly, you want the choice in one box (attended) to update the choices available in the other box (absent).

It's more complex than my case because you will presumably be using multiple select but the long and short is you'll need to use the Change / Update events from Chosen.  It's in the [docs](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) but for completeness:

Change / Update Events

Form Field Change

When working with form fields, you often want to perform some behavior after a value has been selected or deselected. Whenever a user selects a field in Chosen, it triggers a "change" event* on the original form field. That let's you do something like this:

```
$("#form_field").chosen().change( … );
```

Updating Chosen Dynamically

If you need to update the options in your select field and want Chosen to pick up the changes, you'll need to trigger the "liszt:updated" event on the field. Chosen will re-build itself based on the updated content.

```
$("#form_field").trigger("liszt:updated");
```

Comment: Just to add dilan, I solved mine here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17635792/jquery-chosen-how-do-i-update-one-dropdown-according-to-values-selected-in-ano/17641377#17641377